# Can Endermen spawn on Xbox Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

How do you get Endermen to spawn on the Xbox version of Minecraft?

I watched a video of Minecraft and it said they only spawn at night. Is this true?

Comment: What's Xbox Kinect 5?

Comment: They can, and do. I've seen it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman#Xbox_360_Edition), Endermen behave exactly as they do on the PC version of Minecraft.

This means that they will rarely spawn when the block light level is less than 7, in a cave or on the surface, and will only spawn where there is 3 blocks of vertical space, because they are three blocks tall.